# How to avoid CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap returning 0x8007000E

Tags: c++, mfc, direct2d

I have a MFC application where I use Direct2D to draw some images loaded from disk.
When the application is started I create a `IWICBitmapSource` with this methode.

```
IWICBitmapSource *Main::piGetIWICBitmap()
{
    IWICBitmapDecoder *pDecoder = nullptr;
    _AFX_D2D_STATE* pD2DState = AfxGetD2DState();
    HRESULT hr = pD2DState->GetWICFactory()->CreateDecoderFromFilename( sFullPath.c_str(), NULL, GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &pDecoder );
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode *pSource = nullptr;
    hr = pDecoder->GetFrame( 0, &pSource );
    IWICFormatConverter *pConverter = nullptr;
    hr = pD2DState->GetWICFactory()->CreateFormatConverter( &pConverter );
    IWICBitmapFlipRotator * piFlipRotator = nullptr;
    hr = pConverter->Initialize( pSource, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.f, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut );
    hr = pD2DState->GetWICFactory()->CreateBitmapFlipRotator( &piFlipRotator );
    hr = piFlipRotator->Initialize( pConverter, (WICBitmapTransformOptions)WICBitmapTransformFlipHorizontal );
    SafeRelease( &pConverter );
    SafeRelease( &pSource );
    SafeRelease( &pDecoder );
    return piFlipRotator;
}
```

I removed all checks of hr in the above code.

When the program is running I display the image with.

```
void Main::Paint( ID2D1RenderTarget* pclRenderTarget )
{
    ID2D1Bitmap * pBitmap;
    HRESULT hr = pclRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap( pclWICBitmap, &pBitmap );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        // ERROR handling !!!
        return;
    }
    pclRenderTarget->DrawBitmap( pBitmap, stRect );
    SafeRelease( &pBitmap );
}
```

This works most of the time, however occasionally I get:

> 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY) returned from the `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap`.

I have tried to do the `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` when the application starts but this locks the image file until the ID2D1Bitmap is released.

I guess this is because the image is loaded from disk when the `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` is done?
This would also explain why it might not be so good to do `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` every time I need to paint, because the image would be loaded from disk very often.

So the question is, is there a better way to do this so that the image is cached when the application starts without locking the file and I can avoid the potential failure from `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` after startup?

Comment: In `Main::piGetIWICBitmap()`, with `SafeRelease( &piFlipRotator );`, are you not setting the return value to `nullptr`?

Comment: *"is there a better way to do this"* - Use automatic resource management. There is a multitude of smart pointer types to choose from, such as [`_com_ptr_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-class). There are safer ones, but those will already help you understand your code better by removing all those `SafeRelease` calls.

Comment: `SafeRelease( &piFlipRotator);` followed by `return piFlipRotator;` is a bug.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit to fast when I removed the error checking. The `SafeRelease( &piFlipRotator );` was only done if the Initialize failed. I updated the code above accordingly.  Yes the `SafeRelease` sets the pointer to null

Comment: Yes, you could keep the ID2D1Bitmap loaded, this does the disk/CPU => GPU operation so it's costly. As for the problem, difficult to say w/o a complete reproducing code, may come from a part of source you don't show. You should enabled the debug layer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/

Answer (score -1):

I found that the initial question had had some incorrect assumptions. 
The file is not locked until the `ID2D1Bitmap` is released but until the `IWICBitmapSource` is released. 
Therefor it is possible to do the `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` at startup and thereby caching the `ID2D1Bitmap` while running. In case the `ID2D1RenderTarget` is changed it must be recreated. 
The solution for me was to avoid `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` when drawing. This does not answer why `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` returned 0x8007000E, but does answer the question of a better way to do it.